# convert the code with for loop, if and getting the custom object inside if as a return object to lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am new in java8 lambda expression and I am trying to adapt my code to lambda expression, I have the following code:

```
TimeZoneObj  timezone;

for( myObject obj: objectArr)
{
  if((obj.getName).equal("timeZone"))
    {
      timezone=db.getTmezone(obj.getId());
    }
}
```

But I cannot convert it to lambda, can anyone help me to convert the above code to lambda then this way I have a pattern to start with?

Comment: You mean Stream API?

Comment: @Meegoo I think for the filtering part we will need to use stream but I am not sure how to convert this part:  timezone=db.getTmezone(obj.getId());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
TimeZone timezone = Arrays.stream(objectArr)
    .filter(obj -> obj.getName().equals("timeZone")) //filters (i think you know how that work)
    .map(obj -> db.getTmezone(obj.getId())) //this is actually what you needed.
    .findAny().get();
```

But keep in mind that it can throw an `NoSuchElementException` (if it didn't find any value). To make sure it doesn't do that, you can use `orElse(TimeZone)` instead of `get()` to provide default timezone

`.map()` converts `Stream<YourObject>` to `Stream<TimeZone>` using provided `Function<YourObject, TimeZone>`. Basically code that takes `YourObject` and returns `TimeZone`. In this case it's `db.getTimezone(obj.getId())`

PS. Replace `TimeZone` with yours `TimeZoneObj` obviously

PPS. More on how `.map()` works. Let's start with `java.util.function.Function` interface. It's an interface with only one method `apply()` that you need to implement, which makes it a functional interface. It takes object of one type and returns object of another type. Kinda like a regular method in java which you can pass around as an argument.
So, what `.map()` does is it takes a `Function` and uses it to convert original `Stream<SomeObject>` to new `Stream<AnotherObject>`. Full way to use that method would be as follows

```
foo.stream().<AnotherObject>map(new Function<SomeObject, AnotherObject>() {
    @Override
    public AnotherObject apply(SomeObject obj) {
        return sample.conversion.ofSomeObject.toAnotherObject(obj);
    }
})
```

About `<AnotherObject>map()`. `map()` is actually an generic method. You can specify object types that this method will use before the actual call inside of angle brackets (generic). In this case `.map()` uses that object type as a type of new stream. Now, java is actually smart enough to get that type from return type of `Function`, so you don't need to explicitly write it.

`new Function<SomeObject, AnotherObject>() {}` is an anonymous interface (which you kinda have to understand before using lambdas). And it does what it says. It has `.apply()` method that takes `SomeObject` as an argument and returns `AnotherObject` (it is specified in generics up above). `.map()` later can use that method to convert `Stream`s

But that is an awful amount of useless code. So, lambdas come to help and you can replace 6 lines of anonymous interface with one line of lambda
`(obj -> sample.conversion.ofSomeObject.toAnotherObject(obj))` (I kinda hope you understand what lambdas are).

Comment: Thanks can you explain this line:   .map(obj -> db.getTmezone(obj.getId())) //this is actually what you needed.

Comment: This code can *not* return `null`. The method `.get()` will throw an exception for an empty optional.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks, I never noticed that.

Comment: So for avoiding null pointer excepion I should change the code to : TimeZone timezone = Arrays.stream(objectArr)
    .filter(obj -> obj.getName().equals("timeZone")) //filters (i think you know how that work)
    .map(obj -> db.getTmezone(obj.getId())) //this is actually what you needed.
    .findAny().orElse(TimeZone); am i righ?

Comment: @HamedMinaee Yeah. But in `.orElse()` you have to specify default timezone that will be used if none was found in the array (just `.orElse(TimeZone)` obviously won't work, unless `TimeZone` is an object of your type `TimeZoneObj`). Also, if `objectArr` is not an array, but a `java.util.List`, you have to replace `Arrays.stream(objectArr)` with `objectArr.stream()`. But from the name i guessed it was just a default array, so that code should work.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257274/convert-the-code-with-for-loop-and-getting-the-custom-object-when-there-is-if-an?noredirect=1#comment58227002_35257274

Comment: @HamedMinaee The best I can think of are 2 different streams with different filters. One stream cannot return 2 objects of different types.

Comment: @Meegoo so this means looping twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102847/discussion-between-meegoo-and-hamed-minaee).