# convert the code with for loop and getting the custom object when there is if and else if inside loop

Tags: lambda, java-8

Hello everyone I have the following java code:

```
TimeZoneObj  timezone;

for( myObject obj: objectArr)
{
  if((obj.getName).equal("timeZone"))
  {
     timezone=db.getTmezone(obj.getId());
  }
}
```

and I can successfully convert it to lambada as follows:

```
TimeZone timezone = Arrays.stream(objectArr)
.filter(obj -> obj.getName().equals("timeZone")) //filters 
.map(obj -> db.getTmezone(obj.getId())) 
.findAny().oeElse(new TimeZoneObj);
```

but what if I have else if in my main code:

```
 TimeZoneObj  timezone;
  CalendarObj  calenda;

for( myObject obj: objectArr)
{
  if((obj.getName).equal("timeZone"))
  {
     timezone=db.getTmezone(obj.getId());
  }
  else if ((obj.getName).equal("calendar"))
  {
    calendar=db.getCalendar(obj.getId());
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me how to convert above code to lambda?

Comment: @AdiLevin, it is different object types, conditions are probably copy-pasta

Comment: @AdiLevin thank you it is corrected :)

Comment: @HamedMinaee in your first example, the non-lambda & lambda versions are not equivalent. Non-lambda version version will iterate all elements of the array and give you last timezone object, whereas the lambda version will give first occurrence of timezone. The second example makes it more complicated, when do you expect the iteration to stop?

Comment: @mks actuallu the assumption is there is at mos one constraint with the name timezone or calendar so there is either 0 or 1 occurrence for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could do this with two streams:

```
Stream<myObject> timezones = Arrays.stream(objectArr).filter(obj -> obj.getName().equals("timeZone"));
Stream<myObject> calendars = Arrays.stream(objectArr).filter(obj -> obj.getName().equals("calendar"));
TimeZone timezone = timezones.map(obj -> db.getTmezone(obj.getId())).findAny().get();
CalendarObj calendar = calendars.map(obj -> db.getCalendar(obj.getId())).findAny().get();
```

Comment: so is it efficeint to have wo loops? is it not better to use non lambda version?

Comment: @Hamed Minaee: since your original code always loops over the entire array, whereas the two `Stream.findAny` searches will stop at the first match, the two stream ops may be still faster than your single loop. But, of course, this depends on the size of the array and the positions of the matches.

Comment: @Adi Levin: any reason why you split the stream ops in this way?

Comment: @Holger: I was looking for a clean way to do it, without "if"s. But this is not the most performant way.

Comment: My question was, why you split the operations into `Arrays.stream(…).filter(…)` and `.map(…)..findAny().get()`, using an otherwise unnecessary variable holding the `Stream`, instead of using one chain for each operation like `Arrays.stream(…).filter(…).map(…)..findAny().get()`

Comment: Just in order to make a point in the answer that we filter the timezones separately from the calendars. I'm not claiming that this is in any way better than chaining everything together.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in @Adi Levin's answer, yes, lambda is not for all purpose solution.

Having said that, you can try following:

Create a method to map your array element object to target object :

```
    private Object fn(MyObj obj) {
        if (obj.getName().equals("timeZone")) {
            return db.getTmezone(obj.getId());
        } else if (obj.getName().equals("calendar")) {
            return db.getCalendar(obj.getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it to collect your required objects:

```
        List<Object> objects = Arrays
            .stream(objectArr)
            .map(this::fn)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .limit(2)
            .collect(toList());
```

So you final list will have at-most 2 objects. But you still to find out the type of the objects, and order.

Comment: yeah and sometimes you end up with two timezone objects or two calendar objects…